# URL Key becomes Hyphenated after Products Import?

Tags: ce-1.9.2.2, url-key

I have set the URL Key fields in the Dataflow Products Import to a value with no spaces or hyphens. I have also set certain Products to more than one Category, e.g. New and Austria for certain beer glasses.

The problem I see is that in the URL Rewrite Management and the individual Products, I'm seeing hyphens between the words in the URL Key of the Products, e.g. "zipfer-beer-pitcher-large-1-5-litre" (this the actual Title text of the Product) instead of "zipferbeerpitcher" as specified in the CSV Import file.

Do I need to change any code or settings?

Comment: Looks like your URL key column is not being read by Magento. Try exporting a sample and then see if there is anything wrong in there.

Comment: Seems that there is no record for product status in catalog_product_entity_int causing the product not to be displayed in the grid, but to be displayed in Category Products (where product's status is not checked). Thank you. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953584/product-is-not-displaying-in-listing-in-magento-after-import)

Comment: @Barton did that solve your problem? If so, please add it as an answer. If not, please clarify the question

Comment: @fschmengler I fixed the issue by switching off URL Rewrites. I hope that help.